# How to create higher order mailmerge

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge, aspose.words

How can we mailmerge a record that has a table in it?

For instance, while merging the data of customer details in the sales history we want to show the entire sale record corresponding to one row of customer record.

Eg : 
Consider a customer row that has a history table corresponding to each customer.

```
ID, Name, Address, History [Item , Price]

121,XXXX, -------- , [{item1,322},{item2,333}]
122,YYYY, -------- , [{item5,422},{item5,666}]
```

How can we design the csv and mailmerge template for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please download [Invoice Template.doc](https://github.com/aspose-words/Aspose.Words-for-.NET/blob/master/Examples/Data/Mail-Merge/Invoice%20Template.doc?raw=true), [CustomerData.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspose-words/Aspose.Words-for-.NET/master/Examples/Data/Mail-Merge/CustomerData.xml) and try running the following [Aspose.Words for .NET](https://www.aspose.com/products/words/net) code:

```
DataSet pizzaDs = new DataSet();
pizzaDs.ReadXml(MyDir + @"CustomerData.xml");

Document doc = new Document(MyDir + @"Invoice Template.doc");         
doc.MailMerge.TrimWhitespaces = false;

doc.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions(pizzaDs);

doc.Save(MyDir + @"17.6.doc");
```

Hope, this helps. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.